# Crosstalk: filter Polylines in Leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet, rstudio

I can't get crosstalk to work with leaflet and Polylines - here is an MWE:

```
library(crosstalk)
library(leaflet)

theta <- seq(0, 2*pi, len = 100)
dat <- data.frame(
  lon = cos(theta),
  lat = sin(theta),
  t = 1:100
)

sd <- SharedData$new(dat)

map <- leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addCircleMarkers(data = sd, lat = ~lat, lng = ~lon, color = "blue") %>%
  addPolylines(data = sd, lat = ~lat, lng = ~lon, color = "blue")

bscols(
  filter_slider("t", "Time", sd, column = ~t),
  map
)
```

The time filter_slider applies to the circle markers but not the polylines.

Happy to having a go at fixing this in the R leaflet package if someone can point me in the right direction. I.e. what would be required to change / implement? I assume the support is missing on the javascript side as of now?

Answer (score 6):

UPDATE: Good News!
@dmurdoch has submitted a pull request to add support for polylines and polygons.
Using his version of crosstalk, you can now filter leaflet lines/polygons if they're sp objects (note, it doesn't seem to work with sf yet).

First you will need to install this version of crosstalk:
`devtools::install_github("dmurdoch/leaflet@crosstalk4")`

Then you will need to make sure your features are Spatial objects, easy using rgdal or raster: 
`shapes_to_filter <- raster::shapefile("data/features.shp") # raster import to 'Spatial Object'
 shapes_to_filter <- rgdal::readOGR("data/features.shp") # rgdal import to 'Spatial Object'`

Or, if you use sf and dplyr for most spatial tasks (like me) convert an sf object to Spatial:

`library(dplyr)
library(sf)
shapes_to_filter <- st_read("data/features.shp") %>% as('Spatial')  # sf import to 'Spatial Object'`

Then create an sd object for leaflet, and a data frame copy for the filters (IMPORTANT: note how the group for sd_df is set using the group names from the sd_map) :

`library(crosstalk)
sd_map <- SharedData$new(shapes_to_filter)
sd_df <- SharedData$new(as.data.frame(shapes_to_filter@data), group = sd_map $groupName())`

Create crosstalk filters using sd_df:

`filter_select("filterid",  "Select Filter Label", sd_df, ~SomeColumn)`

Create the map using the sd_map object:

`library(leaflet)
leaflet() %>%
addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap") %>%
addPolygons(data = sd_map)`

And any linked tables/charts need to also use the sd_df object:

`library(DT)
datatable(sd_df)`

---

Here's all of the sources for the solution:

[GitHub Issue](https://github.com/rstudio/crosstalk/issues/47)

[Github pull request from dmurdoch to add support for polygons/lines](https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/pull/499)

[Original solution - with outdated method "sd$transform"](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/209203_02f14fea3274448bbbf8d04c99c6051b.html)

[Updated example - with the new "group" method, but I couldnt get their RMD to work](https://gist.github.com/Myles12345/c0fa26ac9572033a851d1f3d057db142)

Answer (score 0):

As previously mentioned by [Bhaskar Karambelkar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42028287/using-crosstalk-with-leaflet-and-polylines):
"crosstalk for now works only with markers and not polylines/polygons"

I hope this changes soon.