# Client side linking leaflet choropleth with plotly R

Tags: r, plotly, r-leaflet, crosstalk

I am trying to link a choropleth map generated using leaflet, with a bar chart from plotly. I want them to be linked [client-side](https://plotly-r.com/client-side-linking.html), i.e. not via Shiny. The behaviour I would like is that when one hovers or clicks on a bar of the bar chart, the corresponding polygon on the map is highlighted and/or vice versa. Best case scenario would it be working both ways, but I'd also be happy with a link in either direction!

I give an example below. I take the [choropleth map example](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/choropleths.html) from leaflet, and use the same data to plot a simple bar chart with plotly. However I can't work out for the life of me how to link the two plots, even after reading about crosstalk, plotly and leaflet documentation, etc.

The problem seems to be that the input to leaflet is a "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame", which can't be used for the plotly bar chart without converting to a standard data frame. I have tried using `SharedData$new()` and `highlight_key()` but the fact that the inputs are different seems to stop me using this concept of shared data. In the plotly examples with leaflet, the examples always seem to use basic data frames with coordinates, which is not the case here because we have polygons.

Note that in the example below I have just converted to a df to be able to plot the bar chart just to illustrate the problem. I know the plots are not linked but I wonder if anyone can give me a clue for how to do this: it would be fantastic. Thanks for any help!

```
library(leaflet)
library(plotly)
library(geojsonio)
library(crosstalk)

### EXAMPLE CHOROPLETH FROM LEAFLET DOCUMENTATION

# From http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/us-states.js
states <- geojson_read("https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/json/us-states.geojson", what = "sp")

bins <- c(0, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000, Inf)
pal <- colorBin("YlOrRd", domain = states$density, bins = bins)

labels <- sprintf(
  "<strong>%s</strong><br/>%g people / mi<sup>2</sup>",
  states$name, states$density
) %>% lapply(htmltools::HTML)

mp <- leaflet(states) %>%
  setView(-96, 37.8, 4) %>%
  addPolygons(
    fillColor = ~pal(density),
    weight = 2,
    opacity = 1,
    color = "white",
    dashArray = "3",
    fillOpacity = 0.7,
    highlightOptions = highlightOptions(
      weight = 5,
      color = "#666",
      dashArray = "",
      fillOpacity = 0.7,
      bringToFront = TRUE),
    label = labels,
    labelOptions = labelOptions(
      style = list("font-weight" = "normal", padding = "3px 8px"),
      textsize = "15px",
      direction = "auto")) %>%
  addLegend(pal = pal, values = ~density, opacity = 0.7, title = NULL,
            position = "bottomright")

### BAR CHART

fig <- plot_ly(as.data.frame(states), x = ~name, y = ~density, type = 'bar')

# BOTH

bscols(mp, fig)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be possible. See responses [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42974140/crosstalk-filter-polylines-in-leaflet).