# Use CROSSTALK to filter polygons on a leaflet map

Tags: r, leaflet, crosstalk

I would like to use crosstalk (i can't use shiny) filters on polygons on a leaflet map. Now, I can't connect the result of the filter to the polygons data. After many investigations it seems impossible. Do you agree ?

For example, on this map I would like only the polygons affected by the selection to be displayed..

Thank you for helping me if you have an idea :)[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be possible. See responses [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42974140/crosstalk-filter-polylines-in-leaflet).